# IQ Test question - numbers inside a grid - math

Tags: mathematics, pattern

[image]

There must be a better way of solving. Can someone tell me what is the correct answer and reasoning? Thank you.

Transcription of the image:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 | 16 |
| 8 | 12 | 52 |
| 14 | 14 | ? |

Comment: This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. As a rule, we generally require users to cite the source of puzzles that they haven't created themselves. Where does this come from?

Comment: @hexomino  hello . one of my freind asked me this

Comment: @xazar How is this a computer puzzle? Does this require you to have a knowledge of computer science/programming to solve? Please consider editing the tags, or if I am wrong, please reply by mentioning me.

Comment: "There must be a better way of solving." Better than what?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer might be

> 108

Reasoning

> If we label the entries in each row as $a,b,c$ then each row satisfies $$\frac{1}{2}ab + a - 4 = c$$
>  For example,  $$ \left(\frac{1}{2}\times 3 \times 4\right) + 3 - 4 = 5$$ $$ \left(\frac{1}{2}\times 5 \times 6\right) + 5 - 4 = 16$$ $$ \left(\frac{1}{2}\times 8 \times 12\right) + 8 - 4 = 52$$ and so $$ \left(\frac{1}{2}\times 14 \times 14\right) + 14 - 4 = 108$$

Comment: perfecttttttt.tnx